# Dissolving points based on easting and northing with statistic type first as aggregate function using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, arcmap, dissolve

I have two points features having point_ID, Easting and Northing fields and want to dissolve based on Easting and Northing with statistic type aggregate as "first" for point_ID, as you do in ArcMap.

How can I achieve this using PostGIS?

Comment: Could you explain what statistic type first means, so that those of us who don't use Arcmap can help?

Comment: can you see `dissolve` in Arctoolbox. you can see there one such option with aggregating attribute as `first`, `last`, `min`, `mean` and `count` etc. see image here http://faculty.unlv.edu/jensen/CEE_468/CEE%20468-668%20GIS%20Applications%20in%20Civil%20Engineering_files/ArcToolboxDissolveTool.jpg

Comment: I added the ArcMap tag, as I don't think non-ESRI users will understand the question. Do you mean you want to dissolve (union in Postgis) those fields that have the same Easting and Northing and use the first point_ID as the attribute for the dissolved feature?

Comment: yes John ..! exactly my thought....